# linked list add node using push function

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, push

```
struct node* AppendNode(struct node** headRef, int num) {
    struct node* current = *headRef;
    // special case for the empty list
    if (current == NULL) {
        Push(headRef, num);   ->why not use & in front of headref?
    } else {
        // Locate the last node
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        // Build the node after the last node
        Push(&(current->next), num);
    }
}


void Push(struct node** headRef, int data) {
struct node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
newNode->data = data;
newNode->next = *headRef; // The '*' to dereferences back to the real head
*headRef = newNode; // ditto
}
```

this is code to add node using push, but i was confuse in this part, Push(headRef, num);

,in here why not using ampersand for headref? if the argument is only headref, is it only copy the pointer to the push function?

headref is a pointer to a pointer to a node, if i call push with argument headref, is it only copy headref to the function and not modify the origin headref?, im not quite sure here, so headref-> head->node (NULL), current point to node(NULL),, then try to push num after headref?

Comment: Since adding `Push`, you can see that both functions have the same first parameter `struct node** headRef` so you just pass `headRef`. In the second case `current->next` is a pointer, so `&(current->next)` is the pointer-to-pointer required.

Comment: @weathervane *headref refer to the pointer to node right? what is the different when i call push using &(current->next) and headref? and why headref is an address? headref is a pointer to pointer that point node right? and if i only call push with headref as argument, is it only copy the pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> headref is a pointer to a pointer to a node, if i call push with
>   argument headref, is it only copy headref to the function and not
>   modify the origin headref?

A handy thing to remember is this: if you want to change an object, you have to pass in the *address* of that object.

Although you have not shown the entire program, it would be safe (I think) to assume that you pass in the address of the pointer to `headRef` when calling `AppendNode`. And it is this address that you pass on to `Push` so that `Push` can de-reference this once and hop to the actual pointer to `headRef` and write something there.

Had you declared `AppendNode` as `AppendNode(struct node* headRef, int num)`, then you would have passed `&headRef` to `Push`.

Comment: so actually when i call push function, i pass a pointer to pointer to node? and the push function itself takes parameter pointer to pointer to node, so it match? but im not quite sure what push(headref, num) do here, if im not wrong after calling push, it will make list : headref -> head-> new node-> null and current point to null

Comment: @fiksx Every location in memory has two attributes (if I may say so) the address and the value. When you do `push(headRef, num)`, you pass a number as the first argument. What does that number mean to you? It is the address of the place containing a value (this value is a pointer (address) let's say `v` to the struct). In the`Push` function you are changing `v` itself. Hope that helps. You will notice that you always pass `NULL` to `Push` so that `Push` can write down some address that it generates by using `malloc`.

Comment: thanks! so when i pass headref is the same as i pass &head which is address of pointer to node? and also is pass NULL is the same as free? when i need to free the malloc memory?

Comment: @fiksx if `head` is defined as `struct node *head`, then it's equal to passing `&head`. To free `malloc`ed memory, pass the pointer returned by `malloc` to `free`. Check this: https://linux.die.net/man/3/free.

Comment: oh okay many thanks, and also for free, i can free the memory in main? after call function and the function return struct to main for example, then i can free the malloc memory in main?

Comment: @fiksx Yes, you can allocate and free memory in main under the circumstances you mention.